# Retrieving information from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When my members login they have a user panel.

However, this is for a game so I'd like to display some information about their characters.
I have 1 table "game" which stores the account information, which I used to create the login session.
But their character information is on a different table called "base"

The 'accid' is the same ID as the one in "game" for each user, so its used more than once to define all the characters on that persons account, i feel like im terrible at explaining so here's an example:

**Base**

```
'accid' , 'character name',
'12659' , 'character 1' , 
'12659' , 'character 2' ,
'10067' , 'character 1' ,
```

**Game**

```
'id' , 'username',
'12659' , 'player 1' , 
'10067' , 'player 2' ,
```

How can I pull all the character information from the "base" table for the logged in persons account only?

Thanks in advance, all help is very appreciated!

Comment: Look into a JOIN statement

Comment: You can `Join` the two tables using `accid` in `Base` table with `id` in `Game` table

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT b.character_name FROM base b LEFT JOIN game g on b.accid = g.id
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, however *noob question* How can I display the results in the session so that each player only see's their chars?

Comment: you can store player id in session and can use it in WHERE condition of above query

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT `id`, `username`, `base`.`character_name` FROM (`game`) JOIN `base` ON `base`.`accid` = `game`.`id`"
```

That is the query you can use to JOIN the two tables

If you want some more simple information

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp